# How can I store a function inside record/data type in Agda?

Tags: function, agda

I've read the doc. It says:

> The strict positivity condition rules out declarations such as
>
> ```
> data Bad : Set where
>     bad : (Bad → Bad) → Bad
>     --     A     B      C
>     -- A is in a negative position, B and C are OK
> ```
>
> since there is a negative occurrence of Bad in the type of the argument of the constructor. (Note that the corresponding data type declaration of Bad is allowed in standard functional languages such as Haskell and ML.).

But it didn't say if there's an alternative way to store a function inside something else (like a data type or a record type).

I've also tried this, which does not compile as well:

```
bin-op : ∀ {ℓ} (A : Set ℓ) → Set ℓ
bin-op A = A → A → A

record Storer {ℓ} (A : Set ℓ) : Set where
  field
    operator : bin-op A
```

So how can I store a function inside a data type/record type/something else I don't know?

Comment: Whenever you get an error message, please post it. What if you try `record Storer {ℓ} (A : Set ℓ) : Set ℓ where`? The strict positivity condition only applies to inductive occurrences and `Storer` is not even inductive.

Comment: Wtf, that works. Could you please explain more or provide a link that I can read the answer from? I know very little about how to use the keyword `inductive` and `coinductive` in Agda. Thanks!

Comment: [Here](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/%E2%80%8E?n=ReferenceManual.UniversePolymorphism) are some docs about universe polymorphism. What I tried to say is that your problem here is not with strict positivity, but with `Storer` being defined in a lower universe (`Set`) than the one it actually belongs to (`Set ℓ`).

Comment: Ok, get it. Thanks!

Comment: Why not answer this question and recieve some rep?

Comment: To add to this, the problem with the "Bad" definition is not just that there's a function type, but that "Bad" itself is the argument type for that function type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the

```
record Storer {ℓ} (A : Set ℓ) : Set where
```

part. Here you state that `Storer` belongs to the `Set` universe, however `Storer` contains `bin-op A` which is in the `Set ℓ` universe, and a record can't be smaller than its fields. Hence the fix is to define `Storer` to be in `Set ℓ`:

```
record Storer {ℓ} (A : Set ℓ) : Set ℓ where
```

Strict positivity is completely unrelated to the problem.

Universe polymorphism in Agda is described in the old [wiki](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/%E2%80%8E?n=ReferenceManual.UniversePolymorphism).